# How do you filter xunit tests by trait with "dotnet test"?

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I have a .NET Core test project that uses Xunit 2.2. Some of my tests are marked with traits.

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Color", "Blue")]
public void TestBlue()
{
}
```

What is the right command line syntax for "dotnet test" to only run tests where the trait Color == Blue ?

I'm using .NET Core CLI 1.0.0-rc4 which uses csproj, not project.json.

I'm trying to use `dotnet test --filter $something`, but whatever I use for $something, I see this error:

> Error: [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7800155] E2ETests: Exception filtering tests: No tests matched the filter because it contains one or more properties that are not valid ($something). Specify filter expression containing valid properties (DisplayName, FullyQualifiedName) and try again.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the answer  (**only** tests attributed `[Trait("TraitName", "TraitValue")]` are executed):

```
dotnet test --filter TraitName=TraitValue
```

Alternatively, you can filter by *not* having a trait value (tests attributed `[Trait("TraitName", "TraitValue")]` are execluded from run)

```
dotnet test --filter TraitName!=TraitValue
```

In my example above, this means I can run:

```
dotnet test --filter Color=Blue
```

More docs here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md

Comment: I still get the error about `(DisplayName, FullyQualifiedName)` any pointers on why this is broken (using cli 1.0.3)

Comment: Not sure, would need more details. As a workaround, you might try using `dotnet-xunit` instead. See http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html

Comment: The following works:

`dotnet test --filter TraitName!=TraitValue`

However only as long as there are some tests decorated with `[Trait("TraitName", "somevalue")]` within the test assembly... if there aren't then no tests get run :-(. Possibly a bug in dotnet test?

Comment: For anyone running into issues using the filter to exclude tests with a particular attribute, there is currently a bug with the tooling described at https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1314

Comment: The issue is now listed as closed (as of June 9, 2017).

Comment: @JamesCrosswell You are right, the only solution I have found is to include dummy Trait attribute on dummy test to test assembly without the Trait.

Answer (score 5):

In the csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.0" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

command line

```
dotnet xunit -trait "Color=Blue"
```